# What is faster in PHP - JSON or string list?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, performance

We like to save a field of boolean flags to `user` object for a right system. So if the user can do this or that. That will be used in most of our controller actions.

To get a good performance we ask what is faster:

1. Save all flags with 0 or 1 in a JSON formatted array and only have to
   ask the array with key if it returns 0 or 1
2. Save only the "1" flags as string list like `can_use_a,can_use_b` and ask the string if it contains the searched key

What do you think? Does anyone have some experience with that?
There will be around 50 to 100 different right flags.

Comment: Is your system so critial you need to worry about a giga second or two

Comment: Do you have actual performance problems? If not, do not premature optimize. Write your code to be legible and maintainable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Since a giga second is 31,7 years I'm pretty sure that actually would be a situation where you'd want to optimize ^^

Comment: @JimL Good point I ment pico second

Answer (score 0):

The json array would be faster.

In the first case, the underlying data structure is a hashmap, which allows retrieval of an element in constant amortized time.

For the second case, there must be a sequential search in order to find whether the value is in the list, which runs in O(n) time.

The json array does use more memory, however.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use true or false instead 0 and 1.
It is much easier to use boolean values and they are less error prone. And one more advantage of using boolean values is that you can check their type also.